# Transfer numbers to matrix

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I formed A as follows:

```
A = [np.zeros((3, 8)) for _ in range(35)]
```

I have a score table that I want to put instead of zeros in each of the rows and columns. that the number of score is exactly equal to the zeros created in A. It means that my scores have 105 rows and 8 columns. the score table is in the Excel file. How do you think I can do this?

Comment: Make A a 3D array, instead of a list of 2D arrays, then reshape it to (105, 8).

Comment: What does Excel have to do with this? You just want a 105 by 8 matrix/table/array, right?

Comment: no In fact, what I mean is that I want to enter the numbers that are in a two-dimensional matrix in Excel into a three-dimensional matrix in the form of A.

Comment: Well, you can the other way: reshape the 2D table/matrix/array to a 3D array. You may need to shift some axes along the way, but that is what `np.rollaxis` or `np.moveaxis` is for.